# How to add variable numbers of parameter in url using expressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, url, console.log, get-request

I'm using express in a nodejs project to call an endPoint and print the parameters after it in console. The url can be:

```
/printInfo?id=xxx&value=xxx 

or

/printInfo?id=xxx

or

/printInfo?value=xxx
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to understand how to read the query string, you just read the values on the `req.query` variable. Here is a simple setup:

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/printInfo', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send({ id: req.query.id, value: req.query.value});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const indexRouter = require('routes/index');

const app = express();

app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`));
```

Now, when you make a request to `http://localhost:3000/printInfo?id=1&value=test` you should see (I have the [JSON Formatter](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter) extension installed):

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "value": "test"
}
```

Show up at that page.

Here is a gif showing how it looks on my machine:

[image: gif of req.query]

Comment: I want to print those values in command prompt and pass them in another function. I need those values in my script file. I'm using express for the first time. sorry, if it's a dumb question

Comment: @Araf You can print the values with console.log() just like any other JS value. To pass them to a function, just pass the req.query.paramName to a function, just like any other value. Maybe post a specific example and I can help?

Comment: thanks. I got it now. It's almost like normal app.get function. thanks a lot

Comment: Ohhh the router.get() was confusing. Sorry, I forgot that most examples don't start with that, I've been in the Express weeds for weeks and it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to do with the data you get from the URL, but `req.query` contains whatever query parameters are in the URL and you can just iterate that object to see what's there:

```
 for (let prop of Object.keys(req.query)) {
     console.log(prop, req.query[prop]);
 }
```

And, here's a simulated demonstration which can run in a local snippet, but you can use the same type of code on `req.query` in Express:

```js
    // define simulated req.query (this is built automatically in Express)
    let req = {
        query: {id: 34506, value: "$400.99"}
    };

    // iterate arbitrary properties of req.query
    for (let prop of Object.keys(req.query)) {
        console.log(prop, req.query[prop]);
    }
```

---

Or, if you know what possible query parameters may be there and you just want to test which ones are there, you can just do like this:

```
if ("id" in req.query) {
    // id property is present
    console.log(req.query.id);
}
if ("value" in req.query) {
    // value property is present
    console.log(req.query.value);
}
```